# Error occurs upon defining args

Tags: python, argparse

Here's the code `main.py` using python2.7

```
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-1","--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
Out[4]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-1', '--image'], dest='image', 
nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Path to 
the image', metavar=None)

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

> usage: **main**.py [-h] -1 IMAGE
>       **main**.py: error: argument -1/--image is required
>       To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>       An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

`SystemExit: 2`

I keep getting error on code line 4 despite following the steps. Is there something I'm not doing right? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like you're running this code inside of your python shell/REPL, in which case argparse is parsing the arguments that started the shell. You should put this code in a file and run the file with the arguments you want to parse.

Comment: How are you running this?  From a shell?  The 'out' and error trapping looks like an `ipython` session.?

Comment: yea, from a shell. Thanks @raylu for correcting my misconception. It's working now running the code from a file with the arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using argparse from within the interactive shell will not work well.  What argparse essentially does it extract arguments from sys.argv and parse them according to the rules that you set up.  As raylu said, I would suggest setting up a python file to run.  For example, in a file called test_argparse.py:

```
import argparse
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-1","--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    print args['image']
```

You can then test this by executing `python test_argparse.py` at the commandline.  This can now be called with the `-1`, `--image`, `-h`, or `--help` flags.  `-h` and `--help` will provide you usage.

Comment: thanks for clearing things up Vorticity. The code is working now